# Video properties like title, description not set with the YouTube API with google client php library

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client, youtube-data-api

I am uploading the video on YouTube using google YouTube API V3 by using google api client in PHP.

My video is getting uploaded successfully but however I am setting the title, description, tags and other properties but they are not populating when I getting the successful response from the API. I mean they are not updating these properties.

Here I am using resumable uploads.

Please help me how can I set the properties like title, tags in the YouTube video. What wrong with this code. I have almost copy all the code from this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#resumable_uploads)

```
    <?php

// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();
/*
 * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
 * Google Developers Console <https://console.developers.google.com/>
 * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
 * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
 * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
 */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '*******';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = '******';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
//$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$scope = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner');
$client->setScopes($scope);
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}
$htmlBody = '';
// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  try{
    // REPLACE this value with the path to the file you are uploading.
    $videoPath = "myfile.mp4";
    // Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
    // Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
    // This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
    // video category.
    $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
    $snippet->setTitle("Mytitle");
    $snippet->setDescription("This id for test purpose");
    $snippet->setTags(array("Yes", "No"));

    // Numeric video category. See
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list 
    $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

    // Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
    // "private" and "unlisted".
    $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
    $status->privacyStatus = "private";

    // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
    $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
    $video->setSnippet($snippet);
    $video->setStatus($status);

    // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
    // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
    // value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
    // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
    $client->setDefer(true);

    // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.

    $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet",$video,
        array("data"=>file_get_contents($videoPath),
         "uploadType"=>"media",  // This was needed in my case
         "mimeType" => "application/octet-stream",
     ));


    // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $client,
        $insertRequest,
        'application/octet-stream',
        null,
        true,
        $chunkSizeBytes
    );
    $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));


    // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
    $statusvalue = false;
    $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
    while (!$statusvalue && !feof($handle)) {
      $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
      $statusvalue = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    }

    fclose($handle);

    // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
    $client->setDefer(false);

    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Video Uploaded</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
        $statusvalue['snippet']['title'],
        $statusvalue['id']);

    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';

  } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }

  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
  // $state = mt_rand();
  // $client->setState($state);
  // $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Video Uploaded</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?=$htmlBody?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think You need to add these libraries:

require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I am using composer, so I only need to require autoload.php of composer. Rest of the require files are automatically include whenever that class is used and this would be handled by the autoload.php. So I don't need to manually include the files that you have suggest me. Also My above code is works perfectly but when I use the chunked upload, the video properties doesn't seems to set. Otherwise it is set.